# Count the same numbers in a string and print them out as stars c++

Tags: c++

I am writing a program which has a string, and then I read through the string and put all the digits in a array using vector and then using count I have to count the same numbers in that array and after that print the number as stars.

Error I am getting is invalid operands to binary expression.

Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include<array>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<string> array;
    string grades = "01211342111153332211111232454444";
    int newarray[31];
    for(int i = 0  ; i < grades.length(); i++){
        array.push_back(grades.substr(i,1));

    }

    int zero = count(std::begin(array),std::end(array),0);
    int one = count(std::begin(array),std::end(array),1);
    int two = count(std::begin(array),std::end(array),2);
    int three = count(std::begin(array),std::end(array),3);
    int four = count(std::begin(array),std::end(array),4);
    int five = count(std::begin(array),std::end(array),5);
   // also used this way int zero = count(array.begin(),array.end(),0); but still getting error.

    for(int i = 0 ; i < one ; i ++){
        cout << '1 - ' << '*' << ' ';
    }
    for(int j = 0 ; j < two ; j++){
        cout << '2 - ' << '*' << ' ';
    }


}
```

Learning C++ so hopefully people go a bit easy on me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many issues here.

First, you are comparing number to strings in `int zero = count(std::begin(array),std::end(array),0);`. You want to compare string to string.

Second, you are trying to `cout` `'1 - '`. `'` is for characters, so you should use `"` instead.

Finally, in the `cout`, you need to loop only on the stars and the space, not the `"1 - "`. And flush the whole thing to print on your console, with either `cout<<"\n";` or `cout<<std::endl;`.

You can try the following:

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> array;
    string grades = "01211342111153332211111232454444";
    int newarray[31];
    for(int i = 0  ; i < grades.length(); i++){
        array.push_back(grades.substr(i,1));

    }

    int zero = count(std::begin(array),std::end(array),"0");
    int one = count(std::begin(array),std::end(array),"1");
    int two = count(std::begin(array),std::end(array),"2");
    int three = count(std::begin(array),std::end(array),"3");
    int four = count(std::begin(array),std::end(array),"4");
    int five = count(std::begin(array),std::end(array),"5");


    cout << "1 - ";
    for(int i = 0 ; i < one ; i ++){
        cout << '*' << ' ';
    }
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "2 - ";
    for(int i = 0 ; i < two ; i ++){
        cout << '*' << ' ';
    }
    cout << "\n";

    /*....*/
}
```